# Stepper Motor Drive Capability

Tags: stepper-motor, torque

I have the set up as shown in the picture below, The stepper Motor is supposed to drive the water Container Up and Down , stirring the solution in the container.
My stepper Motor is a Nema 17 and I'm using a TB6600 driver for micro-stepping.

I don't know if my motor holding torque is too small, or the gear set up is not done properly, because the motor is struggling to drive the container up and down when 400mL of water is thrown is the container.
Can someone help me with calculation for the right Torque to carry this load.
The Overall load is about 600g.

[image]
Note: The system works when the container is empty.

Comment: It's unclear what help you want. It's unclear what your mechanism is. It's unclear how fast the end of the container is rising and falling and what the height differential is or what gross weight it is moving (light and heavy). A lot of stuff missing.

Comment: that, plus questions for necessary torque really feel like they're mechanical, not electrical engineering (even if there's an electrical motor involved)

Comment: Yes the Question is more Mechanical then Electronics, since all the electronics involved seems are operating, Like I said the system work when the container is empty.

Comment: The Speed on how fast the Container move up and down is set by the drivers toggle options, I understand that more speed mean less hoding torque. So the speed is not an issue right now, what I want is the motor to be able to lift up and bring down the contain, with a net weight of about 600g.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mechanical engineering rather than electrical engineering.  You probably want a gear motor if you really want to do it like that, but most people wouldn't build a solution stirrer with that kind of mechanism at all.

Comment: You can buy steppers with gear down modules to increase the torque

Answer (score 1):

Power = Force X Speed in linear mechanics.

In rotatory mechanics:
Power = Torque X Angular Speed.

So, if you reduce the speed, you will increase the torque for the same power (and motor).  If you use a motor with a transmission attached to it, you will reduce the speed but increase the torque.  You can find many NEMA-17 motors with transmission included for about 20 dollars on eBay.  Even, if the torque magnification es enough, you can hold the position of the load without energizing the motor.  And that is the magic of mechatronics, it includes Electrical, Mechanical and Electronics Engineering, plus Computing and Programming :o)